# ubuntu-emulator doesn't start my images

Tags: ubuntu-emulator

when I run `ubuntu-emulator run myinstance`
I get:

```
Cannot run specified emulator environment
```

My Development System:
Ubuntu 14.04 lts running virtual as a kvm-qemu image.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but I find that error in the code on line 210 here: https://code.launchpad.net/~sergiusens/goget-ubuntu-touch/x86-emu/+merge/216626 it seems to be triggered by the code in line 207 if my logic isn't flawed.

Answer (score 1):

I got it. With this command it works.

I have to append the password parameter:

```
sudo ubuntu-emulator create mynewinstance --arch=i386 --password=test
```

Only thing is, the emulator does just start through a ssh remote connection.